# Is the GA R package the best Genetic Algorithm package?

Tags: r, algorithms, genetic

I am learning about Data Science and I love the Healthcare part. That's why I have started a blog and my third entry is about using Genetic Algorithm for solving NP-Problems. 
This post is https://datasciencecgp.wordpress.com/2015/01/31/the-amazing-genetic-algorithms/

I have some expertise with GA package solving problems like the TSP, but do you know any most powerful R package?

Thanks so much!

Comment: This is too broad. What specifically are you hoping to learn? what problems are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to use Genetic Algorithms and try to learn when to apply, for example answers like Stephan are welcome to improve the investigation with Genetics and R.

Comment: Hi Sean, I've focused more my question, is it OK?

Comment: I found the glmulti package useful for GA-like fitting.  One of the problems with "best package" questions is that without a good understanding of the nature of the problem, the data, and the goal - the means to get to the answer are unknonw.

Answer (score 5):

For such questions, I like to go to the [Task Views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/) on CRAN, since the packages noted there are, to a degree, pre-vetted by the R community. I'd trust those a tiny bit more than just googling myself.

The [Machine Learning Task View at CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) says:

> Packages [rgp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgp/index.html)
>   and
>   [rgenoud](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgenoud/index.html)
>   offer optimization routines based on genetic algorithms. The package
>   [Rmalschains](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmalschains/index.html)
>   implements memetic algorithms with local search chains, which are a
>   special type of evolutionary algorithms, combining a steady state
>   genetic algorithm with local search for real-valued parameter
>   optimization.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephan! I will do a deep sight in this packages.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Stephan's answer (I am unable to comment), there is actually an Optimization task view on CRAN that is even more relevant:

[CRAN Task View: Optimization and Mathematical Programming](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html)